# Django model choice field: How to remove empty field ? Django form exclude a value from the list of choices?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

how to remove a empty field?

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
    (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
    (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
    (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
    (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
]
year_in_school = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
)
```

Django form exclude a value from the list of choices example: 'Junior'?

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = ['year_in_school ']
```

Comment: Just delete it from your array? Is there a reason you need to keep it in your array?

Comment: @alvo yes because we use two forms, one where I give a default value in the view year_in_school = 'Junior', and on the other I want to remove or hide the value 'Junior' from the list, i dont wont to render manually on template exclude the value 'Junior'